# Wifi very Slow with Intel Wireless 1000 N

Tags: intel-wireless

ive trouble with my wi-fi connection. Browsed about 2 days here and didnt find a solution. My connection is about 300kb/s with a 16k dsl connection.

```
##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:01 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop #####

Ubuntu

##### lspci #####

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2131]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:481b Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

iwldvm                214950  0 
mac80211              546051  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               152049  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              409394  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    18673  0 

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig #####

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC addr eth0>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC addr wlan0>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.19  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:c7ff:fe60:d0c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6338153 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:1523047 (1.5 MB)

##### iwconfig #####

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"StuggiRK"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC addr StuggiRK>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:130  Invalid misc:161   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search localdomain

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC addr eth0>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [StuggiRK] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC addr wlan0>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    GloveC:          Infra, <MAC addr GloveC>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA WPA2
    FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270: Infra, <MAC addr FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA WPA2
    WLAN-E4BC55:     Infra, <MAC addr WLAN-E4BC55>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2
    WLAN-540612:     Infra, <MAC addr WLAN-540612>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA2
    FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7320: Infra, <MAC addr FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7320>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    o2DSL:           Infra, <MAC addr o2DSL>, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2
    *StuggiRK:       Infra, <MAC addr StuggiRK>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.19
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1
    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             8.8.4.4

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iw reg get #####

country DE:
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 40), (N/A, 26), DFS
    (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), NO-OUTDOOR

##### iwlist channels #####

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #####

Channel occupancy:

     2   WLAPs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
     1   WLAPs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
     4   WLAPs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC addr StuggiRK>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"StuggiRK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002d9c3846cd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1234604ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC addr StuggiRK>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002de5cc7159
                    Extra: Last beacon: 144ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC addr o2DSL>
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"o2DSL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004802c13ca2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC addr GloveC>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"GloveC"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000287bd32281
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC addr FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000287b60b897
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC addr WLAN-E4BC55>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WLAN-E4BC55"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001fe8708ff07
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC addr WLAN-540612>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WLAN-540612"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003a6e946151
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

564756383533394A5710240008312E33322E3030301042000A4A3330313231353132321054000800060050F204000110110014576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020084103C000103

##### module infos #####

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     CC4D1BA11C1EF73A6ABDE53
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:8D:B5:FD:6E:29:9C:CE:49:47:DA:CA:A6:6F:45:9D:B4:AC:CE:24
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     C2D0F3DFCA289585C100E36
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:8D:B5:FD:6E:29:9C:CE:49:47:DA:CA:A6:6F:45:9D:B4:AC:CE:24
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

##### module parameters #####

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 1
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 1
wd_disable: 1

##### /etc/modules #####

lp

##### blacklists #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

##### rc.local #####

exit 0

##### udev rules #####

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC addr eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x0084 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC addr wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

:15:98:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=1 ID=30174 PROTO=2 

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install the last iwlwifi from backports3.16-1. After you download it, extract it in folder and type:

> `$make defconf-iwlwifi`
>   `$sudo make`
>   `$sudo make install`
>   `$sudo reboot`

If it does not work, try to type in a terminal:

> `$echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf`
>   `$echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
>   `$sudo reboot`